# How do I provision a Vagrant box before it's been instantiated?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I would like to create a Vagrant box from the output of another Vagrant box. I'd like to do it from within Vagrant. I would like to run `vagrant init` or `vagrant up` and have it do the following steps:

1. Run this command to convert from .bin to .vdi `vboxmanage convertfromraw --format vdi ../build/qMp_3.2.1-Clearance_VirtualBox_x86_factory_20180325-0702.bin qmp-nycmesh-3.2.1.vdi`
2. Create an instance based on that .vdi

I have this Vagrantfile, but 1) it is not executing the shell script before trying to create the box, and 2) it trying to download a box instead of using the VDI given.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Hello"
  #config.vm.box = "nycmesh-qmp-openwrt"
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "64"
    vb.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', "../build/qMp_3.2.1-Clearance_VirtualBox_x86_factory_20170406-2203.vdi"]
    #vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--ostype", "Linux26"]
  end
end
```

With `config.vm.box`, it gives

```
$ vagrant up
==> default: Box 'nycmesh-qmp-openwrt' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Downloading: nycmesh-qmp-openwrt
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. ...
Couldn't open file .../nycmesh-qmp-openwrt
```

And commenting `config.vm.box` gives

```
$ vagrant up
vm:
* A box must be specified.
```

Vagrant 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I found I can specify a placeholder box and can just swap it out before it boots, but it still has to copy the gigabyte sized image and when you use `vagrant destroy` it doesn't delete the placeholder image. This is less than ideal.

I realized the Vagrantfile is just Ruby so I was able to script the VDI creation. I wasn't able to delete the placeholder image because there's no hook to insert yourself between the instance being created and the swapping of the disk image.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  latest_bin = `ls -t ../build/*.bin | head -1`.strip
  #latest_bin = Dir.glob('../build/*.bin').sort{ |a,b| File.new(a).stat <=> File.new(b).stat }.last
  vdi_file = 'nycmesh-qmp-openwrt.vdi'
  system "vboxmanage convertfromraw --format vdi #{latest_bin} #{vdi_file}" unless File.exist?(vdi_file)
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
  config.vm.network "public_network"
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "64"
    # add the newly created build disk firmware
    #vb.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE', '--port', 0, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', "none"]
    vb.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE', '--port', 0, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', "nycmesh-qmp-openwrt.vdi"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--ostype", "Linux26"]
  end
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "" do
    # delete the placeholder dummy hdd image. there should be a better way.
    # NO WAY TO GET THE DUMMY HDD FILE NAME AFTER THE INSTANCE IS CREATED AND BEFORE THE NEW VDI IS INSTALLED!
    # id = File.read(".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id") 
    # hdd_file = `vboxmanage showvminfo #{id}`.split(/\n/).grep(/IDE \(0, 0\): /).first.split(/ /)[3]
    # puts hdd_file
    # File.delete(hdd_file) if hdd_file.index 'centos-7-1-1.x86_64.vmdk'
  end
end
```